# How to split a string that includes sign characters

Tags: python, split, character

How can I split a string that includes "sign characters" but no spaces? For example:

```
aString = '1+20*40-3'
```

I want the output to be:

```
['1', '+', '20', '*', '40', '-', '3']
```

I tried this:

```
aString.split('+' and '*' and '-')
```

but that didn't work.

Comment: Time to learn about Regular Expressions.

Comment: Note that: `('+' and '*' and '-') == '-'`; `split` *excludes* the character you split on from the output; and you need to figure out how to express that `'+'` and `'2'` are separate but `'2'` and `'0'` should stay together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regular expression to do this task in python. The code will be:

```
import re
aString= '1+20*40-3'
print re.findall('[+-/*]|\d+',aString)
```

output:

```
  >>> 
  ['1', '+', '20', '*', '40', '-', '3']
```

Refer documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

Comment: Perfect, thanks man. What if I want to add an exponent to the string (**) ? For example aSting='1**2'